# Trying to add bootstrap to angular-cli-build.js but file missing. ng serve works with file absent. What replaced angular-cli-build.js file?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-cli

Currently following tutorial in using bootstrap with angular-cli. Tutorial declares that I need to put `'bootstrap/dist/**/*'` inside of angular-cli-build.js file. Can't locate.

Other solutions to this problem say to change:

**Package.json** file

```
"angular-cli": {},
```

to

```
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack",
```

This gives me an error.

`ng serve` already functions correctly.

node version : v6.6.0

npm version : 3.10.7

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back to the Angular-Cli documentation and followed the bootstrap steps. If all else fails. Ignore the tutorial ;)

[https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#creating-a-build]